# Show ASCII characters in django template (python 2)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, character-encoding, django-templates

I'm trying to show the word "Año" in a template but I get an emtpy string.

I do have

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the beginning of my views.py

I've tried in my view:

```
 unicode(myString)

 myString.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

I've tried in my template:

```
 {{n.name|safe}}
```

None of the methods are working for me.

In my mysql table the word is fine.

In my views I get the data like this:

```
cursorMYSQL.execute(query)
table_names = cursorMYSQL.fetchall()
```

In my template:

```
{%if table_names%}
    {% for n in table_names %}
        <option value="{{n.name}}" name="{{n.name}}">{{n.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{%endif%}
```

Comment: django has no issues in showing unicode, the problem is probably to do with how you pass `n` in your context, you should show how you do that in your view

Comment: Note that `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` simply tells the Python parser that the encoding of your script's source uses UTF-8, which lets it interpret UTF-8 string literals in the script itself correctly. It has **no** effect on how your script processes Unicode. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Just a question: Why do you get the data in Django directly from an SQL cursor? You don't use the ORM?

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah, that's another story, long story short, I've been asked to do it this way, that's all.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah! Ok! I read this answers in another questions so I thought it had to do with this.

Comment: From the use of the `unicode()` function I assume you're using Python 2. You should **always** mention the Python version (preferably via the appropriate tag) with Unicode questions, since Unicode handling is quite different between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I'm using python 2.

Comment: are you certain your mysql database is encoded in utf-8?

Comment: I changed my mysql table charset to "CHARSET=utf8mb4" but it's not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it with

```
myString.decode('latin1')
```

I had to check my DB as Joel Goldstick said, as some tables were enconded in utf-8 and some in latin1, which I didn't know.

Changing my mysql table charset to CHARSET=utf8mb4 didn't work either.